# The html file created by Systrace blank

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, systrace

I followed the tutorial of systrace on Jelly Bean from
[Android developer systrace](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/systrace.html)

The procedure seems right, and create a html file for me, but it displays nothing in browser which is just blank. I can see lots of source code in html file.

I tried firefox and IE, who can tell me what's wrong?

Comment: it could only be seen in google chrome browser...

Comment: I had the exactly same problem (i.e. nothing shows up in Firefox and IE). But Chrome worked. Not sure why. Maybe it's a Google thing. __ sol

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. resolved using chrome 22.0.1229.95.
I think lastest chrome will be ok